# ExpressionEngine - Not sure how to fix this 404 not found error

Tags: http-status-code-404, expressionengine

I am trying to setup a localhost version of our site and have a problem getting this setup correctly.

Both our live and localhost site have this directory structure:

```
/na_cms/expressionengine/templates/default_site/c.group
/na_cms/expressionengine/templates/default_site/j.group
/na_cms/expressionengine/templates/default_site/default.group
/na_cms/expressionengine/templates/default_site/inc.group
```

On our live site, CSS files in our templates are accessed like this:

```
href=“css/c/modal.css”
src=“j/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js”
```

How do I get rid of the 404 not found errors for the CSS and javascript files on the localhost site?

My config file has

```
$config[‘rewrite_short_tags’] = TRUE;
```

Comment: The relative URLs are correct for CSS and javascript files in our live site, I can navigate to them just fine. But on the localhost site, the same relative URLs don't work.

Comment: They are in the same relative directory structure as in the live site.

Comment: [quote]what are they on the localhost site[/quote]How is that not the same thing as asking if the paths to the files are the same? The source code is the same on both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm obviously using assumptions here until further information gleamed...

You're using templates to hold your JS and CSS, rather than external files (Nothing wrong with that), so they're not technically relative URLs - it's pulled from the database so you won't have any more of a path than template group and template.  The browser will not be targeting these template files directly, it will be EE providing them.

In your j.group folder I'm assuming you have a file called "jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js.js", which relates to a template group called "j" and a template called "jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"?

What I'm a bit confused at is "css/c/modal.css", as this is indicating a template group called css, but you've stated your template group is called "c" and the template is "modal.css".  Possibly this was a mistake, or you've got a "css" template group and falling into the index template...?

Firstly, check your template folder settings in EE, Design -> Templates -> Template Manager, then "Global Template Preferences".  Look for "Basepath to Template File Directory".  I'm assuming that you copied the online database to your local, rather than a new fresh install?

If you're using htaccess rewriting, check that is working on your local.

Failing that, try changing the paths to the CSS and JS to use the path variable:

```
src=“{path='j/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js'}”
```

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/path.html

Comment: I did not setup this folder structure. This site was built a little over 18 months ago and I came on about 7 mos ago. Personally, I don't like the way it is laid out. There are files all over the place and I am working on a reorganization plan now. WWhat I don't understand is how EE interperets css/c as the c.group and j as the javascript group. It works on the live site but I cannot make it work on the local site.

Comment: If I use the {path='...'} option, it makes the urls look like this: 
http://localhost:8040/EE_MP/index.php/css/c/style and 
http://localhost:8040/EE_MP/index.php/j/jquery-1.6.min.js

However. I can access the CSS file directly with its URL just fine, but the javascript file I can't access directly with that URL.

Comment: If the JavaScript URL is not appearing, then it could be either being blocked by the htaccess, or the spellings wrong.
When you say: "I can access the CSS file directly with its URL just fine" - you mean on the "localhost:8040/EE_MP/index.php/css/c/style" path yes?
Can you confirm if you have a template group called "CSS"?
Also can you confirm if you have an external folder in your web root called "CSS", as my guess is that the CSS isn't being pulled from the template, it's being pulled from an external file in webroot/css/c/ folder.  It could also be they've used symlinks?!?

Comment: Yes, I used that URL for the syle css file and the file showed in my browser. The url to the jquery-1.6.min javascript file just didn't show anything. I didn't get any 404 or 403 errors. I do not have a template group called CSS, all the css files are in a template group called c. All the javscript files are in a template group called j. I do not have them in a directory off the webroot called /css/c or /j, either. I have disabled the .htaccess as well. It must be some kind of EE configuration that is making it serve the paths for CSS files as css/c/ and javascript files as j/.

Comment: BTW, I'm using EE 2.1.0, Also, the way I knew the links to the CSS were working and the links to the javascript were not working was I opened the source in FF (View Source) and clicked on the links.

Comment: Doubtful, I've not heard of anything regarding EE configuration that could do this.  Have you got any rewriting extensions installed (e.g. Deviant)?

Comment: What happens if you enter c/modal.css, if it works on local, it should also work on the live.

Comment: I have since decided to begin from scratch and not try to "recreate" our site as it is now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Extensions: Allow EE Code v1.4, Magpie RSS Parser v1.3.5, XML Encode v1.3                          
Modules: Channel v2.0.1; Comment v2.0; Email v2.0; Emoticon  v2.0; jQuery v1.0; Pages v2.0; Query v2.0); RSS v2.0; Search v2.0; Statistics v2.0